# SQL hourly data aggregation in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, aggregate, query-performance

I am a newbie with database so I'm seeking your help with this one.

I have a table containing time series data.

```
2012/01/01 00:10, 10
2012/01/01 00:30, 5
2012/01/01 01:00, 10
2012/01/01 01:40, 10
2012/01/01 02:00, 20
```

The table is storing interval based data by keeping only the upper limit of the interval. For example the first row represents an interval from [00:00 - 00:10] with a value of 10, second row represents an interval from (00:10 - 00:30] with a value of 5 and the third one represents an interval from (00:30 - 01:00) with a value of 10.

I need an efficient query in Postgres to aggregate hourly data for a structure like the one described above. So the result would be something like this:

```
2012/01/01 00:00, 2012/01/01 01:00, 25
2012/01/01 01:00, 2012/01/01 02:00, 30
```

Note that the time-series data is big so any help with indexing this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
dan

Comment: In your sample data, e.g. `2012/01/01 00:10, 10`, are all those values in a single column, or is the comma a column delimiter? Also, are the exact hours (1:00, 2:00, 3:00, etc.) guaranteed to be stored in the time series table, or might it skip over the :00 and have entries such as `2012/01/01 03:50` followed by `2012/01/01 04:10`?

Comment: What if you have an hour with no source data? Do you still want an output like `2012/01/01 04:00, 2012/01/01 05:00, 0`? or should that hour just be omitted from the summary?

Comment: @dartonw - the comma is a column delimiter. So the date time and the value are different columns in a table. 
The exact hours are guaranteed to be always stored.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select
  date_trunc('hour', t - interval '1 minute') as interv_start,
  date_trunc('hour', t - interval '1 minute')  + interval '1 hours' as interv_end,
 sum(v)
  from myt 
    group by date_trunc('hour', t - interval '1 minute')
order by interv_start
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/35a36/9)

As for the index: you could try a function index on `date_trunc('hour', t - interval '1 minute')` but I'm not sure postgresql can use it.

Comment: Thank you, my boss is happy. But if you need real science-based _precise_ approach, please, study to work with window functions. PostgreSQL supports them natively: http://no0p.github.io/postgresql/2014/05/08/timeseries-tips-pg.html

Comment: upvoted! how would you do this if this was 30 mins instead of 1 hour